# Is possible to set which-key package minimum height?

Tags: which-key

I'm using the `which-key` package and I checked the docs and it seems you can set the max height for the buffer with `(setq which-key-frame-max-height 20)` , but I can't seem to find a way to set the minimum height. I want to leave at least and empty line if the which key buffer is just a line height.

```
;; --- Which Key Mode ---

(use-package which-key
  :ensure t

  :defer t
  
  :config
  
  (setq which-key-idle-delay 3.0)
  (setq which-key-separator " → " )
  (setq which-key-unicode-correction 3)
  (setq which-key-prefix-prefix "+" )
  (setq which-key-side-window-location 'bottom)

  ;; This line doesn't seem to do anything
  (setq which-key-min-display-lines 13)
      
  )
```

Shows just two lines:

[image]

Comment: does `(setq which-key-min-display-lines 2)` do what you need?

Comment: It seems to ignore that variable, I just updated my question with my current `which-key` config.

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of key bindings that is one line. When I apply your minimum height of '13', the one line turns into 3 lines, justified left. Setting it to larger values seemed to have no further effect. Unclear to me what is meant by 'lines.'

It's 50-50 whether the lines would be above or below the listed key bindings. I opened an issue at GitHub. We'll see what happens.